# How to increase layout_marginBottom by a number of pixels?

Tags: android, android-layout, margin, floating-action-button, android-layoutparams

In a game I display a custom View and a FAB in a FrameLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.slova.GameView
        android:id="@+id/gameView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_white" />

</FrameLayout>
```

However the FAB is shown too low and obscures the light blue bar at the bottom:

[image: screenshot]

I need to increase the `layout_marginBottom` by the height of the light blue bar (indicated by the red arrows at the above screenshot), so that the FAB is moved up.

I do know the height of the bar in pixels (the content of my custom View is scaled by a Matrix) and I think I know the right place for this action (the `onSizeChanged` method in my custom View) - but my difficulty is getting ahold of the FAB's `layout_marginBottom` value.

How to access and change it please? I have tried:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

    int h = mBar.getHeight();

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mFab.getLayoutParams();

    // how to add h to layout_marginBottom here?

    mFab.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

By the way I do have two methods to translate between `dp` and `px` if needed here:

```
public static float px2sp(Context context, float px) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return px / scaledDensity;
}

public static float sp2px(Context context, float sp) {
    float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    return sp * scaledDensity;
}
```

Comment: Is the bottom blue bar part of the GameView?

Comment: Yes part of the GameView, its height in pixels is `mBar.getHeight()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin property is part of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` Class, so you have to cast it to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams param = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
param.bottomMargin = mBar.getHeight();
fab.setLayoutParams(param);
```

Comment: I don't see the property `params.bottomMargin` in my Java code, there is only `params.height` and `params.width`.

Comment: Oh that's a kotlin code.. Will convert it into java

Comment: I understand it is Kotlin, but can't find the matching properties in Java when doing `ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mFab.getLayoutParams();`

Comment: Margin property is not the Part of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` Class it's part of `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` Class so you have to cast it to FrameLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Casting to `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` has worked, thank you. However there was no method called `setBottomMargin()`, but I could set the property `bottomMargin`.

Comment: Oh.. I was blindly converting it from Kotlin.. I thought there would be a setter for that property in java

Comment: That is funny :-) Good hint about the casting though, thanks